# API to resolve %% variables

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I am working with the C# Event Log API in Windows (essentially everything in [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

I have an `EventMetadata` object and pull its `Description` property to retrieve the message template for an event.
Generally, these templates look similar to the following:

```
Network interface reports message %1
```

These variables are easily replaceable with actual data whenever I receive an event.
(`EventLogRecord.Properties` match up to the placeholders)

Here is where my problem comes in. The `EventLogRecord.Properties` sometimes contain different kinds of placeholders. These always begin in %% and I cannot find a way of resolving them.

As an example:

```
// This method is triggered when a new event comes in
async public static void ListenerEvent(object s, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs args) {
  var evt = (EventLogRecord)args.EventRecord;

  // This method retrieves the template from a ProviderMetadata object
  // And replaces all %n with {n}
  // So that we can string.Format on it
  var tmp = TemplateCache.TemplateFor(evt);

  // Need this since the indices start with 1, not 0
  var props = new List<object> {string.Empty};
  props.AddRange(evt.Properties.Select(prop => prop.Value));

  // Now the message should be human-readable
  var msg = string.Format(tmp, props);
}
```

Using the above example template, the Properties might be ["%%16411"] and now I end up with the following message

```
Network interface reports message %%16411
```

I figure my question now is, how do I replace this `%%16411`?
I have looked into `ProviderMetadata` and the rest of its properties but none seem to match up.

Any help figuring out how to resolve these placeholders (or even what they are/where they come from) is appreciated.
An event that shows this behaviour is 5152, as found here: http://community.spiceworks.com/windows_event/show/452-microsoft-windows-security-auditing-5152

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363669(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx